# Magento 1.4 Delete all product images

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

Is there a script available or easy process for deleting all product images,
as I can't seem to find anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can remove the multiple  product images. You will have to remove them from database table as well as folder structure. I would suggest you to follow the given link so that you would be more clear

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53356/magento-delete-all-product-images

Thanks